# vim showing weird characters on screen in terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, vim, openbox, unicode

So I just installed ubuntu on my Netbook and switched to the openbox window manager.

When I open up VIM in a terminal and hit `j` when I am at the top of the file or hit `k` from the bottom of the file, some weird unicode characters seem to show up. Please find below a screenshot of this.

This is really disturbing when editing a file. Blocks the content for me till I go over it with the cursor.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image: vim-weird-characters]

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in gnome-terminal. I'm not getting this in xterm though.

Comment: I fixed this issue by removing some t_ti, t_te, t_SI, t_EI code (that wasn't relevant to Ubuntu) https://github.com/amcsi/vimfiles/commit/23e3a230ab1f0551cc5ce58d1a3a234254967234

Comment: I had similar problem. I just found out by commenting config out and in that it was caused by "set visualbel"

Answer (score 1):

This is because of visual bell.
you can solve this be deleting or commenting this line from your .vimrc file

```
`set visualbell`
```

EDIT:

I still don't know though how to use visualbell and not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I changed from Tilix to Terminator & experienced a similar problem.  My solution was based on one given in the first link but I needed a few extra changes (the bell and other solutions didn't help me, I needed to clear the screen).

This was added to the end of my virmc.

```
" Solve extra characters on vim screens in terminator in Linux
" Enable different cursors based on the mode from
" https://github.com/mjedmonds/dotfiles/commit/41c1d4639d7b2b047d260602f27a80695cf73f9c
" Information on cursors to complete it from
" https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes"

if has("autocmd")
  au BufNewFile,VimEnter,BufEnter,InsertLeave * 
    \ silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[2 q"' | redraw!
  au InsertEnter,InsertChange *
    \ if v:insertmode == 'i' | 
    \   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[6 q"' | redraw! |
    \ elseif v:insertmode == 'r' |
    \   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[4 q"' | redraw! |
    \ endif
  au VimLeave * silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[ q"' | redraw!
endif

let &t_SI = "\<Esc>P\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7\<Esc>\\"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>P\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7\<Esc>\\"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>P\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7\<Esc>\\"
```